# Add Inventory Summary Explorer and Generic Inquiries to the Acumatica Mobile

Tags: mobile, acumatica

I would like to add the Inventory Summary Explorer to the Mobile screen. Currently, I have the reports such as "Labels" working fine. I also have the "Stock Items" working, but it does not get me down to the Location / Lot level like the Inventory Summary Explorer does.

Is there a way to get the Inventory Summary Explorer to show on the Mobile Screen.

As well as Generic Inquiries.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the XML mapping to get the **Inventory Summary** screen show on a mobile device:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sm:Screen DisplayName="Inventory Summary" Id="IN401000" Type="FilterListScreen" Icon="system://Display2"
           xmlns:sm="http://acumatica.com/mobilesitemap" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <sm:Container Name="Selection">
    <sm:Field Name="InventoryID"/>
    <sm:Field Name="ExpandByLotSerialNumber"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Warehouse"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Location"/>
  </sm:Container>

  <sm:Container Name="InventorySummary" FieldsToShow="6">
    <sm:Field Name="InventoryID"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Warehouse"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Location"/>
    <sm:Field Name="OnHand"/>
    <sm:Field Name="LotSerialNumber"/>
    <sm:Field Name="EstimatedTotalCost"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Available"/>
  </sm:Container>
</sm:Screen>
```

[image]

[image]

***One important thing to mention:*** at this point, **Inventory Summary** can not be  fully supported by mobile framework. To resolve this, make sure you distribute the following `InventorySummaryEnq` BLC extension together with your XML mapping (the issue had been forwarded to Acumatica engineering team and should be addressed in future releases):

```
public class InventorySummaryEnqExt : PXGraphExtension<InventorySummaryEnq>
{
    public PXSelect<InventorySummaryEnquiryResult> ISERecords;
    protected virtual IEnumerable iSERecords()
    {
        bool invokeBaseView = true;
        foreach (var inserted in ISERecords.Cache.Inserted)
        {
            invokeBaseView = false;
            yield return inserted;
        }
        if (!invokeBaseView) yield break;

        foreach (InventorySummaryEnquiryResult record in Base.ISERecords.Select())
        {
            var result = Base.ISERecords.Cache.Locate(record) ?? Base.ISERecords.Cache.Insert(record);
            yield return result;
        }
        Base.ISERecords.Cache.IsDirty = false;
    }

    protected void InventorySummaryEnqFilter_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Base.ISERecords.Cache.Clear();
    }
}
```

Now about Generic Inquiries...

As a rule, inquiry and generic inquiry screens in Acumatica are composed either of the **Result** grid only or a combination of the **Filter** header form and the **Result** detail grid.

A generic inquiry screen with no parameters should be mapped with the `SimpleScreen` type. The sample below is to map the ***Sales Activities*** GI (GI000001) shipped with Sales Demo template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sm:Screen DisplayName="Sales Activities" Id="GI000001" Type="SimpleScreen" Icon="system://Display1"
           xmlns:sm="http://acumatica.com/mobilesitemap" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <sm:Container Name="Result" FieldsToShow="4">
    <sm:Field Name="OwnerID" ListPriority="99"/>
    <sm:Field Name="OwnerDescription"/>
    <sm:Field Name="CreatedDate" ListPriority="98"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Summary" ListPriority="97"/>
    <sm:Field Name="ActivityClass"/>
    <sm:Field Name="ActivityType"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Status" ListPriority="96"/>
  </sm:Container>
</sm:Screen>
```

[image]

And this is how **Sales Activities** will look on a mobile device:

[image]

A generic inquiry screen with parameters should be mapped with the `FilterListScreen` type. The sample below is to map the ***Sales Orders and Quotes*** GI (GI000006) also shipped with Sales Demo template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sm:Screen DisplayName="Sales Orders and Quotes" Id="GI000006" Type="FilterListScreen" Icon="system://Notebook"
           xmlns:sm="http://acumatica.com/mobilesitemap" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <sm:Container Name="Filter_">
    <sm:Field Name="OrderType"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Customer"/>
    <sm:Field Name="IncludeClosedOrders"/>
    <sm:Field Name="FromDate"/>
    <sm:Field Name="ToDate"/>
  </sm:Container>

  <sm:Container Name="Result" FieldsToShow="6">
    <sm:Field Name="OrderType" ListPriority="99"/>
    <sm:Field Name="OrderNbr" ListPriority="98"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Status" ListPriority="97"/>
    <sm:Field Name="CustomerName" ListPriority="96"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Date" ListPriority="95"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Currency"/>
    <sm:Field Name="OrderTotal" ListPriority="94"/>
  </sm:Container>
</sm:Screen>
```

[image]

The **Sales Orders and Quotes** filter on a mobile device:

[image]

And the **Sales Orders and Quotes** result list:

[image]